# How to add multiple parameters in arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

already sorry for my stupid question but googling for it was not successful

How can I add multiple parameters in an arrow functions. I want to add some properties "props" to the following function.

```
  const changeLocationHandler = async event => {
    try {
      let hasError = false;
      let response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/game/location', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth.token
        },
        body: { 
        }
      });
      const responseData = await response.json();
      if (!response.ok) {
        hasError = true;
      }
      if (hasError) {
        alert(responseData.message);
      }  
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error)
    }
  }
```

It does not accept someting like

`const changeLocationHandler = async event props => {`

or

`const changeLocationHandler = props => async event => {`

Thanks in advance

Comment: `(event, props) => { ... }` https://javascript.info/arrow-functions-basics

Comment: Only 1-argument functions can lack the `()`

Comment: Questions like this are often answered by a google search like "mdn arrow function"

Comment: Sorry guys for asking this question - as I said it will be a dumb one and yes, I saw the mdn webpage but did not understand it. Anyhow thanks for the anwers, it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the arguments in parentheses for this to work.

```
const changeLocationHandler = async (event, arg2, arg3) => {
```